# Find the m-th largest separation

Tags: algorithms, optimization

The m-th largest number in a list of n numbers can be found in $O(m \log n)$ using a max-heap. This avoids sorting.

Suppose I'm interested not in the actual numbers, but separation between adjacent numbers (after sorting). Is there an algorithm to find the m-th largest separation without having to sort the numbers? More precisely, the $m$ large separations create $(m+1)$ buckets, and I want to find the bucket each item belongs to (I don't care about the ordering within a bucket).

For example, the largest separation ($m=1$) problem can be solved by creating $(n+1)$ bins of equal size between the min and the max, and finding the bin each item belongs to. By pigeonhole principle, one of the bins will be empty, and this is the position of the largest separation.

Comment: The [BFPRT Quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) algorithm works in $O(n)$-time for selection. The max-heap is not needed.

Comment: Also, could you define what a separation is (for clarity)?